# no conversion from 'const char *' to 'int'

Tags: char, int, type-conversion

Can someone help me with this issue I'm having?  I'm getting the 'no conversion from 'const char *' to 'int' on my first 'if' statement line.  Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

```
char            Vtype,
            Vehicle;
int             HI,
            HO,
            MI,
            MO,
            Ctime,
            Catime,
            Btime,
            Basub,
            Ttime,
            Tasub;
double          Ctotal,
            Batot,
            Bbtot,
            Btotal,
            Tatot,
            Tbtot,
            Ttotal;
const double    C_Rate = 1.25,
            B1_Rate = 2.00,
            B2_Rate = 2.50,
            T1_Rate = 3.75,
            T2_Rate = 4.50;
cout << "TYPE OF VEHICLE: ";
cin >> Vtype;

    if (Vtype == "C" || Vtyp == "B" || Vtype == "T")
    {
        cout << "HOURS IN: ";
        cin >> HI;
        if (HI < 0 || HI > 23)
        {
            cout << "Hours cannot be less than 0 or greater than 23!\n";
            cout << "Please enter a valid hour.\n";
            cin >> HI;
        }
```

Thank you,

T

Comment: Can you show us the declaration of `Vtype`? Sounds like it's an `int` and you're comparing it to strings. Have you tried changing that declaration to `std::string Vtype;`?

Comment: Hi Ed, here are my declarations. I left it a char because I only need to verify the character entered. char   Vtype,
    Vehicle;
int    HI,
    HO,
    MI,
    MO,
    Ctime,
    Catime,
    Btime,
    Basub,
    Ttime,
    Tasub;
double   Ctotal,
    Batot,
    Bbtot,
    Btotal,
    Tatot,
    Tbtot,
    Ttotal;
const double C_Rate = 1.25,
    B1_Rate = 2.00,
    B2_Rate = 2.50,
    T1_Rate = 3.75,
    T2_Rate = 4.50;

Answer (score 2):

If Vtype is a `char`, compare it to characters:

```
if (Vtype == 'C' || Vtype == 'B' || Vtype == 'T') {
}
```

The compiler is accusing you of comparing `const char *` to `int` because as far as C++ is concerned, a character *is* an integer.

Or, if you need to compare it to strings, declare it as `std::string`.

Comment: I thought that's what I was doing. 'C' is a character I'm trying to compare Vtype against and if Vtype is declared as a char, i'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: In your OP, you have `"C"` in double quotes. In C++, that's a string literal. Try single quotes, apostrophes, tick marks: `'C'`. My example differs from your code in that respect. That makes it a character literal. Somebody's liable to pop in and go ape***t about semantics here, but in effect, `"C"` will be treated as a pointer to an array of characters. If you're familiar with Perl or JavaScript, you might expect both quote characters to be interchangeable, or nearly so. In C++, they are not. In C++, 'C' is semantic sugar for the integer 67.